# UiimagePicker Perview mode full screen with custom overlay in Iphone 6 and 6+

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6.1, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

Currently I am using UIImagePicker View for custom camera. I used following to fix Perview mode in Iphone 5.Not I had to provide support for Iphone 6 and 6+ .Should I adjust transform scale through coding for every screen.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"overlayView" owner:self options:nil];
self.overlayView.frame = self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.frame;
self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView;
self.overlayView = nil;

//For iphone 5+
//Camera is 426 * 320. Screen height is 568.  Multiply by 1.333 in 5 inch to fill vertical
CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 71.0); //This slots the preview exactly in the middle of the screen by moving it down 71 points
self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = translate;

CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformScale(translate, 1.333333, 1.333333);
self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = scale;
```

Comment: Have you tried on iPhone 6Plus simulator?

Comment: No I had tried in iPhone 6 device.

Comment: Following is the link of screenshot. In this black area is coming downside. I want camera preview in full screen.http://screencast.com/t/K5MnC1KHnvbd

Comment: It means for sy value you require higher range, try increasing sy value in CGAffineTransformScale. Refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformScale

Comment: Should I need to hardcode value for every device.

Answer (score 1):

enter image description here

```
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
            // set the aspect ratio of the camera
            float heightRatio = 4.0f / 3.0f;
            // calculate the height of the camera based on the screen width
            float cameraHeight = screenSize.width * heightRatio;
            // calculate the ratio that the camera height needs to be scaled by
            float scale = screenSize.height / cameraHeight;
            // move the controller to the center of the screen
            self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, (screenSize.height - cameraHeight) / 2.0);
            // concatenate the scale transform
            self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform, scale, scale);
```

But Due to this I am also getting same extra area that is not displayed in preview mode. I am getting same error previously but the area was less. How can I capture only that area that is visible.

Comment: Following are the screenshotRefer following screen shots for more clearance

In Iphone 6 - [http://i.imgur.com/gQNvLlr.jpg] (in preview mode)

[http://i.imgur.com/agZmWPI.png][2] (captured image)

In iphone 5 - [http://i.imgur.com/odp5ZYe.jpg][3] (in preview mode)

http://i.imgur.com/R17cE68.png (captured image)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is any other solution.

But as of my knowledge, you would require to check device version and accordingly change [CGAffineTransformScale](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformScale):

There are many ways to check device version, here is one of the ways:

```
CGAffineTransform scale;

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
            if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector: @selector(scale)]) {
                CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;


         CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
            result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);

            if(result.height == 960) {
                NSLog(@"iPhone 4, 4S Resolution");
                scale = CGAffineTransformScale(translate, sx, sy); // sx and sy are CGFloats
            }
            else if(result.height == 1136) {
                NSLog(@"iPhone 5, 5C, 5S Resolution");
                scale = CGAffineTransformScale(translate, sx, sy); // sx and sy are CGFloats
            }
            else if(result.height == 1334) {
                NSLog(@"iPhone 6 Resolution");
                scale = CGAffineTransformScale(translate, sx, sy); // sx and sy are CGFloats
            }
            else if(result.height == 1920) {
                NSLog(@"iPhone 6 Plus Resolution");
                scale = CGAffineTransformScale(translate, sx, sy); // sx and sy are CGFloats
            }
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Standard Resolution");
        }
    }
```

Once you have scale reference ready you can set:

```
self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = scale;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: for my question I got one solution